# Should things like an app's mailer system run in a separate channel as shown in this example?

Tags: go, architecture, channel

Imagine a web service with a fair amount of different routes. Some of them trigger transactional emails being sent to the user. It seems weird to initialise a *mailer* instance, for instance something using `github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go/service/sns` every time a request wants to send something.

Instead I'd assume there's one *mailer* instance and everything happens on a separate channel to which a `message` gets posted to.

### Example

I created a simple example illustrating the problem. A global `Mailer` instance gets configured once, the `Index` handler asks for a channel and passes a `Message`.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "log"
    "net/http"
    "os"
)

// Message is the custom type used to pass the channel
type Message struct {
    To      string
    Subject string
    Body    string
}

// Mailer is responsible to send out emails
type Mailer struct{}

// send sends out the email
func (m *Mailer) send(message Message) {
    fmt.Printf("Sending email to:`%s`\nSubject: %s\n%s\n\n", message.To, message.Subject, message.Body)
}

// Messages returns the channel to which messages can be passed
func (m *Mailer) Messages() chan<- Message {
    cm := make(chan Message)

    go func() {
        msg := <-cm
        m.send(msg)

        close(cm)
    }()

    return cm
}

// mailer is a global var in this example, would probably be part of some
// sort of app context that's accessible from any handler.
//
// Note the mailer is NOT handler-scoped.
var mailer = Mailer{} // would this be thread-safe?

// Index handler
func Index(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    m := Message{"email@example.com", fmt.Sprintf("visited `%s`", r.URL.Path[1:]), "Lorem ipsum"}
    mailer.Messages() <- m

    fmt.Fprintf(w, "Sent out email with subject line `%s`\n", m.Subject)
}

func main() {
    http.HandleFunc("/", Index)

    port := os.Getenv("PORT")
    if port == "" {
        port = "8080"
    }

    if err := http.ListenAndServe(":"+port, nil); err != nil {
        log.Fatal("ListenAndServe: ", err)
    }
}
```

#### Output

Visting `http://localhost:8080/hello-world` will render…

> Sent out email with subject line `visited `hello-world``

… and log

> sending email to `email@example.com`:
>     visited `hello-world`
>     Lorem ipsum

### Questions

1. Is this the right approach?
2. Is it thread-safe – if not how to get it thread-safe?

Comment: There's no need to close channels like `close(cm)`, if there's never any more receive operations

Comment: @JimB initially I didn't close it but as soon as a second request came in it got blocked.

Comment: You must be doing something you're not showing here. You only ever receive one message on the channel, so there's no need to close.

Comment: @JimB I see, I tried a slightly different version of this example earlier which caused a problem when not closing it. Just tried the example given in the post and you're right, it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not really doing anything in this example, but passing message over channels is always safe -- channels are one of the basic concurrency primitives in the language. You are leaving yourself open to the possibility of race conditions, depending on what `send` actually ends up doing. Another way to handle this is to have `send` receive from a single channel.

```
type Mailer struct{
    Messages chan Message
}

func (m *Mailer) send() {
    for message := range m.Messages {
        fmt.Printf("Sending email to:`%s`\nSubject: %s\n%s\n\n", message.To, message.Subject, message.Body)
    }
}

var mailer *Mailer

func Index(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    m := Message{"email@example.com", fmt.Sprintf("visited `%s`", r.URL.Path[1:]), "Lorem ipsum"}
    mailer.Messages <- m

    fmt.Fprintf(w, "Sent out email with subject line `%s`\n", m.Subject)
}


func main() {
    mailer = &Mailer{
        // buffer up to 100 message to be sent before blocking
        Messages: make(chan Message, 100),
    }
    // start the mailer send loop
    go mailer.send()

    ...
```

Comment: Ah, great! I was wondering if a single channel would do and how this would work. Just to clarify, in this case the message queue could grow up to 100 … and if for some reason 150 end up in there, it blocks the handler but will stop blocking as soon as `send()` has worked it back down to 100 or less?

Comment: correct, that's how buffered channels work. A send blocks until there's space n the buffer.